# ScrollView inside PullToRefreshScrollView does not scroll

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

Well I have in the main_layout a pulltorefresh viewgroup inside of that layout I have two fragments - One of these fragments has a ScrollView layout - so basically one fragment has an image and the other is scrollable with a bunch of details. I use this code to disable the pulltorefresh from intercepting the touch events that are made on the scrollable fragment part:

```
        descriptionScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.detail_item_description_holder_scroller);
        descriptionScrollView
                .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on
                        // touch of child view
                        descriptionScrollView
                                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        pullToRefreshScrollView.getRefreshableView()
                                .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

This blocks the pulltorefresh from scrolling when I touch on the scrollview part of the screen - the only problem is that the scrollview layout is not scrollable at all. When I remove the PulltoRefresh from my main_layout this scrollview from fragments layout becomes scrollable..

Please help